# Error while starting Smart Target kettle job in Fredhopper with Experience Optimization

Tags: web8, fredhopper, experience-optimization

I am implementing Experience Optimization in WEB 8, with `Fredhopper version 7.5.2.4`. 
I configured fredhopper as per [SDL document](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D) and configured the micro services and registered those in the discovery service.
While publishing I am getting the following error in deployer service log ::

```
2016-08-31 11:33:22,456 ERROR AbstractFredhopperDeployer - Unable to start kettle job in Fredhopper. please check configuration and FH Installation
2016-08-31 11:33:22,456 ERROR AbstractFredhopperDeployer - Runjob method returned: 404
2016-08-31 11:33:22,457 ERROR AbstractFredhopperDeployer - Unable to start kettle job in Fredhopper ; Please check configuration and Fredhopper Installation
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to start kettle job in Fredhopper; Please check configuration and Fredhopper Installation
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:49) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.FileSystemDeployer.deploy(FileSystemDeployer.java:13) [smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:213) [smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) [smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) [smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:108) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:76) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:113) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:250) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:108) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:71) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.lambda$pipelineRunnable$1(TransactionManager.java:345) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-08-31 11:33:22,459 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to execute onSuccess event in phase: Deployment Commit Phase for transaction: tcm:0-492-66560
2016-08-31 11:33:22,460 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-492-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to start kettle job in Fredhopper. Please check configuration and Fredhopper Installation
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:58) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.FileSystemDeployer.deploy(FileSystemDeployer.java:13) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.utils.SmartTargetXMLUtils.persistFredhopperXML(SmartTargetXMLUtils.java:213) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperOutputBuilder.persistFredhopperXML(FredhopperOutputBuilder.java:119) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule.process(FredhopperDeployerModule.java:76) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:108) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:76) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.CommitPhase.onSuccess(CommitPhase.java:113) ~[cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runSafeEvent(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:250) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:108) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:71) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.lambda$pipelineRunnable$1(TransactionManager.java:345) [cd_deployer-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to start kettle job in Fredhopper; Please check configuration and Fredhopper Installation
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.fredhopper.AbstractFredhopperDeployer.triggerKettleJob(AbstractFredhopperDeployer.java:49) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:8.1.1]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

When I checked the `catalog01` folder I found the component details.But unfortunately the Smart Target kettle job is not processing those XML files.

Also when I tried to access the Business manager for this one I get an Error page.[image] Where as the Fredhopper business manager is working fine for another index server, which uses the default kettle job file.[image]

I came across this [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/smarttarget-installation-cannot-run-kettle-job) where it has been mentioned it may be due to version mismatch.

Can any one help me with the correct version for WEB 8 Experience Optimization. Or is there any other work around?

Comment: The official line is that we support Fredhopper 7.5.2.x - so this should not be the issue. However it might be worth investigating. Unless Peter Kjaer happens to show up here, I would suggest opening a ticket in parallel to trigger SDL to look at it. The other server where it works, is it the same version of Fredhopper? "Unable to start kettle job" hints at a configuration and/or permissions issue.

Comment: @NunoLinhares : Thanks. I will log a ticket. and yes the other version is  in the same server. I have added 2 index servers in the topology. The second one is running on the default port [8180 ] not connected to WEB 8.The first one is running on port 10180 where I am deploying the Tridion content.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you get a 404 indicates that the API extension isn't working. Coupled with the error in the Business Manager, I'm certain you are running into a known issue that has been fixed in the newer cloud releases.

The smarttarget_api_extension.jar file mistakenly included some javax.servlet classes (from transient dependencies) and they can interfere with the compilation of the JSP files in Fredhopper.

Considering the extension hasn't changed, a safe workaround would be to use the 2014 SP1 version of smarttarget_api_extension.jar if you have it available. Otherwise, contact Customer Support and we will provide you with a working JAR file.

Comment: I tried with ST 2014 SP1 jar, but it did not work and got the message "Please wait
The Business Manager will be available when the indices are loaded.
(This page will refresh in 10 seconds) ". I have contacted SDL support for this.

Comment: That's the normal message when you haven't published anything to Fredhopper yet (or it hasn't finished processing anything yet). So perhaps it did work just fine?

Comment: Got the issue. I have added 2 index servers in the topology.txt. As per SDL support I have removed the other Index server entry from the topology file [As it should contain only 1 index server]. And for the error page I have replaced the smarttarget_api_extension.jar with that of Smart Traget 2014 SP1. Now it is working.