# SDL web8 XO integration with fredhopper-7.5-revision-19.zip with latest version is FAS 7.5.2.11 business manager issue

Tags: web8, smarttarget, fredhopper, sdl-tridion

I did managed to tried to installed the **fredhopper-7.5-revision-19.zip** with latest version is **FAS 7.5.2.11**.

Using the following documents reference
https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Select+a+different+initial+FAS+version

Now I can see indexer is started. but when we try to access admin business manager it's getting this below error page.
[image]

But indexer is up and running.
[image]

Seems to be looks like qserver issue.

I looked at the logs agent and kitchen no errors.

**indexer instance fredhopper.logs:** following error  message is appearing

```
2016-10-18 23:32:57,611 ERROR [http-nio-8180-exec-1] TransformServlet.java:168 50311 Cannot get source document `/admin/login.jsp': `An error occured while processing an XML resource' || Velu@IV-SMART:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS release/7.5.2@0e7783750333263bfba590aef6216700b51e4ff4
java.io.IOException: An error occured while processing an XML resource
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.forwardRequest(TransformServlet.java:255)
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.service(TransformServlet.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fredhopper.bm.AccessLogSessionFilter.doFilter(AccessLogSessionFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fredhopper.servlets.AdminAvailabilityFilter.doFilter(AdminAvailabilityFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [329] in the generated java file: [C:\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\fredhopper\org\apache\jsp\admin\login_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.forwardRequest(TransformServlet.java:253)
    ... 29 more
2016-10-18 23:38:02,763 ERROR [http-nio-8180-exec-3] TransformServlet.java:168 50311 Cannot get source document `/admin/login.jsp': `An error occured while processing an XML resource' || Velu@UNB-SMART:C:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS release/7.5.2@0e7783750333263bfba590aef6216700b51e4ff4
java.io.IOException: An error occured while processing an XML resource
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.forwardRequest(TransformServlet.java:255)
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.service(TransformServlet.java:158)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fredhopper.bm.AccessLogSessionFilter.doFilter(AccessLogSessionFilter.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.fredhopper.servlets.AdminAvailabilityFilter.doFilter(AdminAvailabilityFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [329] in the generated java file: [C:\fredhopper\data\instances\indexer\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\fredhopper\org\apache\jsp\admin\login_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.fredhopper.transformservlet.TransformServlet.forwardRequest(TransformServlet.java:253)
    ... 29 more
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while starting Smart Target kettle job in Fredhopper with Experience Optimization](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/error-while-starting-smart-target-kettle-job-in-fredhopper-with-experience-optim)

Comment: Although it may not be obvious, this is actually the same as the following issue - so check out my answer to this question: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/error-while-starting-smart-target-kettle-job-in-fredhopper-with-experience-optim/15447

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate question. The underlying cause may be the same, but it's valuable for others to be able to search for both of the questions and the problem descriptions that they contain. I'd suggest leaving both open, but perhaps answering one by referring to the existing answer and noting any differences.

Comment: @PeterKjaer: Actually I'm installed SDL Web8.1 and then installed Experience Optimization for SDL Web 8.1.1 not Smart Traget 2014 SP1
still not sure should we use ST 2014 SP1 jar instead of Experience Optimization for SDL Web 8.1.1\Experience Optimization 8.1.1 release\Content Delivery\roles\fredhopper\extensions\smarttarget_api_extension.jar

Comment: Yes. There is a problem with the smarttarget_api_extension.jar that comes with 8.1 -- so you can work around it by using the one from 2014 SP1. The code hasn't changed anyway, it's just that when it was rebuilt in 8.1 some unnecessary transient dependencies were accidentally included and those cause a conflict with the ones included in Fredhopper.