# How to quickly add Experience Optimization to an existing Environment, website build on SDL Web 8.1.1 and DXA 1.6 framework

Tags: web8, dxa, experience-optimization, dxa-1.6

We have a working website build on SDL Web 8.1.1 and DXA 1.6 framework Now we need to add Experience Optimization on top of it. I found two different installation guides of Experience optimization, one provided for SDL Web8 and other for DXA 1.6.

1. Should I need to execute steps mentioned in both installation guides or not ?
2. Is the Fredhopper a mandatory prerequisite for Experience Optimization?
3. We need some very basic personalization to do in website at present and for that can we have a very basic installation steps of Experience optimization ; want to avoid non-mandatory items installation steps at present. Need to park all non-mandatory items installation for later phase 2.

**A. DXA 1.6 (Experience Optimization module)**

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v6/GUID-0B2799A4-6B18-4242-A15C-9F0E0CD28020

**B. SDL Web 8 (Quick Guide to installing Experience Optimization**

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-28D61030-27C1-4F1F-9117-A32E9F8FE16D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, but you can skip the step to install XO in your website/app; that is covered by the DXA XO Module installation.
2. Yes.

Comment: Installation steps mentioned in the sdl doc not working. The very first for step for fredhopper installation  "Open a command prompt and run the following command in the target folder to start the deployment agent: bin\deployment-agent" This is not working, even after waiting for half hour it shows no output/error on command prompt

Comment: I think you just have to leave it running in its  own command prompt (alternatively, you could create a scheduled task for it, which starts on startup).

Comment: Note that there is an issue with the XO 8.1.1 Fredhopper extension. See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/error-while-starting-smart-target-kettle-job-in-fredhopper-with-experience-optim/15447

Comment: The deployment agent is indeed meant to keep running. It is what accepts and processes the other commands, like start and stopping instances. That's why it's easier to have it as a scheduled task running in the background.