# Experience optimization - Fredhopper Cannot run kettle job

Tags: smarttarget, sdl-tridion, web8.5, experience-optimization

I am having the same issue mentioned in the [link](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/smarttarget-installation-cannot-run-kettle-job), I thought I will ask a sperate question as this is again happening with other versions while installing with Experience Optimization.

Initially I have tried with all below fredhopper versions with Web 8.5.

- fredhopper-7.5.2.10
- fredhopper-7.5-revision-15
- fredhopper-7.5-revision-19

I can see that the xml is getting copied to /data/fas-xml-incremental folder but it is not getting indexed, am I missing something?

I can see below error in kitchen.log

```
data\instances\deployment\log\kitchen.log:ERROR 21-03 14:36:48,866 - Start Busi
ess Manager - Unable to complete execution, the qserver of instance 'indexer' i
 still unable to serve requests.
data\instances\deployment\log\kitchen.log:ERROR 21-03 14:36:48,880 - Kitchen -
inished with errors

data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:38:18,696 ERROR [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] FacetRuleCompiler.java:129 20095 Facet configuration `facet_1' is incompatible with the current data: Attribute type [categories] is not present in the navigation index for universe [catalog01]. The configuration will not contribute any facets to the front end. || Administrator@WIN-XXXX:D:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:39:42,718 ERROR [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] FacetRuleCompiler.java:129 20095 Facet configuration `facet_1' is incompatible with the current data: Attribute type [categories] is not present in the navigation index for universe [catalog01]. The configuration will not contribute any facets to the front end. || Administrator@WIN-XXXX:D:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:41:41,083 ERROR [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] FacetRuleCompiler.java:129 20095 Facet configuration `facet_1' is incompatible with the current data: Attribute type [categories] is not present in the navigation index for universe [catalog01]. The configuration will not contribute any facets to the front end. || Administrator@WIN-XXXX:D:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.4@32caeb2eb85a1c8a2b7ae430a47fef7e2fe34432
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:41,548 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:41,550 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:42,626 ERROR [pool-1-thread-2] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:42,630 ERROR [pool-1-thread-2] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:43,581 ERROR [pool-1-thread-3] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:43,582 ERROR [pool-1-thread-3] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:44,414 ERROR [pool-1-thread-4] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:44,414 ERROR [pool-1-thread-4] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:45,260 ERROR [pool-1-thread-5] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:45,261 ERROR [pool-1-thread-5] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:45,689 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] Digester.java:1585 Begin event threw exception
data\instances\indexer\log\fredhopper.log:2017-03-21 14:44:45,690 ERROR [pool-1-thread-1] WorkerThread.java:84 Job: /D:/fredhopper/bin/../data/instances/indexer/custom/../../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
```

Content of STjob.kjb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <name>STJob</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <job_version/>
    <job_status>0</job_status>
  <directory>&#47;</directory>
  <created_user>-</created_user>
  <created_date>2013&#47;07&#47;02 13:44:41.058</created_date>
  <modified_user>-</modified_user>
  <modified_date>2013&#47;07&#47;02 13:44:41.058</modified_date>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
<job-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<size_limit_lines/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_JOB</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_JOB</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>JOBNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>JOBNAME</name></field><field><id>STATUS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STATUS</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>STARTDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STARTDATE</name></field><field><id>ENDDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ENDDATE</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>DEPDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>DEPDATE</name></field><field><id>REPLAYDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPLAYDATE</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field></job-log-table>
<jobentry-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>JOBNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>JOBENTRYNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEPNAME</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>RESULT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>RESULT</name></field><field><id>NR_RESULT_ROWS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>NR_RESULT_ROWS</name></field><field><id>NR_RESULT_FILES</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>NR_RESULT_FILES</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field><field><id>COPY_NR</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>COPY_NR</name></field></jobentry-log-table>
<channel-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_NAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_NAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_COPY</name></field><field><id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name></field><field><id>FILENAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>FILENAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_ID</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_REVISION</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_REVISION</name></field><field><id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field></channel-log-table>
   <pass_batchid>N</pass_batchid>
   <shared_objects_file/>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <name>START</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SPECIAL</type>
      <start>Y</start>
      <dummy>N</dummy>
      <repeat>N</repeat>
      <schedulerType>0</schedulerType>
      <intervalSeconds>0</intervalSeconds>
      <intervalMinutes>60</intervalMinutes>
      <hour>12</hour>
      <minutes>0</minutes>
      <weekDay>1</weekDay>
      <DayOfMonth>1</DayOfMonth>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>302</xloc>
      <yloc>115</yloc>
      </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Success</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SUCCESS</type>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>597</xloc>
      <yloc>110</yloc>
      </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Move Files</name>
      <description/>
      <type>MOVE_FILES</type>
      <move_empty_folders>N</move_empty_folders>
      <arg_from_previous>N</arg_from_previous>
      <include_subfolders>N</include_subfolders>
      <add_result_filesname>N</add_result_filesname>
      <destination_is_a_file>N</destination_is_a_file>
      <create_destination_folder>N</create_destination_folder>
      <add_date>N</add_date>
      <add_time>N</add_time>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <date_time_format/>
      <nr_errors_less_than>10</nr_errors_less_than>
      <success_condition>success_if_no_errors</success_condition>
      <AddDateBeforeExtension>N</AddDateBeforeExtension>
      <DoNotKeepFolderStructure>N</DoNotKeepFolderStructure>
      <iffileexists>do_nothing</iffileexists>
      <destinationFolder/>
      <ifmovedfileexists>do_nothing</ifmovedfileexists>
      <moved_date_time_format/>
      <create_move_to_folder>N</create_move_to_folder>
      <add_moved_date>N</add_moved_date>
      <add_moved_time>N</add_moved_time>
      <SpecifyMoveFormat>N</SpecifyMoveFormat>
      <AddMovedDateBeforeExtension>N</AddMovedDateBeforeExtension>
      <simulate>N</simulate>
      <fields>
        <field>
          <source_filefolder>${EXECUTIONPATH}..&#47;..&#47;..&#47;..&#47;${INSTANCE}&#47;data&#47;fas-xml-incremental&#47;${UNIVERSE}&#47;</source_filefolder>
          <destination_filefolder>${EXECUTIONPATH}..&#47;..&#47;${INSTANCE}&#47;data&#47;xml&#47;incoming&#47;batch&#47;</destination_filefolder>
          <wildcard>.*\.xml$</wildcard>
        </field>
      </fields>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>459</xloc>
      <yloc>116</yloc>
      </entry>
  </entries>
  <hops>
    <hop>
      <from>START</from>
      <to>Move Files</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>Y</unconditional>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Move Files</from>
      <to>Success</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>N</unconditional>
    </hop>
  </hops>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
</job>
```

Comment: Looks like it has problems loading the STJob.kjb file. Could you make sure you've copied in the right one from the installation files?

Comment: I did so,  I copied it from SDL Web 8.5\Experience Optimization\Content Delivery\roles\fredhopper\extensions 

is there any specific fredhopper version that supports?

Comment: No, any 7.5 version will work. Perhaps there are some file system permissions missing so it cannot read it?

Comment: I tried giving full permission to everyone for fredhopper folder :( , has it been any time success at first or second shot??

Comment: I don't understand what you just asked. Could you add the content of your STJob.kjb file to the question?

Comment: Also, you say you've tried 3 different versions. Did you get the exact same error in all 3 versions? Which one are you using right now?

Comment: Yes.. all are having the same error, now I am using fredhopper-7.5.2.10,
One thing I noticed.. 
after setting up, if i restart my system and start indexer, it works fine, but if I ran reindex command, the indexer gets  stopped.. :( 

then I need to kill all the process or restart the machine for the indexer to start again, but both ways.. kettle job is not running..

Comment: @PeterKjaer I have updated question with STJob.kjb file content

Comment: I am not sure of this helps.. I could see below error in the log

2017-03-23 07:27:01,044 FATAL [Fred-Initialisation-Thread] QServerInitContextListener.java:163 50359 Engine startup failed || Administrator@WIN-JNBIGOFVSRI:D:\fredhopper\data\installations\FAS fas-7.5.2.10@203c2edadcdcf04808ea9ae926db8e6b80e60b26 
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.fredhopper.frob.FredEngine.registerBMMBeans(FredEngine.java:1443) 
at com.fredhopper.jsp.QServerInitContextListener$1.run(QServerInitContextListener.java:110) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I have tried a lot of different versions of fredhopper, and all have problems in starting the instances. I have run manually the bin/run-etl-job  to first load the metadata.xml, and some deployed packages, but it doesn't run automatically when I publish/deploy content to fredhopper. And I get the same error in the fredhopper.log of the instance "../etl/STJob.kjb failed to execute due to org.apache.commons.digester.xmlrules.XmlLoadException: Error at line 12 char 121: Default conversion to org.pentaho.di.job.JobEntryType failed., see kettle log for details
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have been struggling with the same problem during last week and I think the answer to this question is on this [previous issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15445/error-while-starting-smart-target-kettle-job-in-fredhopper-with-experience-optim?rq=1).

It seems to be a problem with the SDLWeb 8.5 `smarttarget_api_extension.jar` file with some dependent classes.

As [@PeterKjaer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/141/peter-kjaer) coments, the extension hasn't changed, a safe workaround would be to use the `2014 SP1 version` of smarttarget_api_extension.jar.

I have put the old jar in my custom folder of the instances, and restart them, and the kettle job `STJob.kjb` is now working, and indexing the components published to fredhopper.

Comment: That particular problem was fixed in 8.2.

Comment: You mean 8.2 version of fredhopper? but this version is not supported by SDL Web

Comment: No, I mean the smarttarget_api_extension.jar issue was fixed in SDL Web 8.2 (a cloud-only release) - and therefore also in 8.5. So I think you had a different issue, or you didn't have the 8.5 version of that JAR file.